# Set initial (default) instances in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am building a Blog App and I am trying to add `inbuilt initial instances in django admin` so when user clone the repo , then user will see several initial `blogs` every time even after `reset the database`.

I didn't find anywhere to set the initial data. I also tried [How to set initial data for Django admin model add instance form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000950/how-to-set-initial-data-for-django-admin-model-add-instance-form) But it was not what i am trying to do.

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

I tried to use [Providing data with fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures) But I have no idea , How can I store in.

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixtures still need to be loaded manually. You can add that step into installation instruction, something like "to load example data, install the provided fixture via `manage.py loaddata ./my_blog_fixture.json`

If you want to have the data inserted into database without any user's action, then you are looking for a [Data Migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

that's a kind of database migration which does not change the database structure in any way, but it executes a custom command, eg. inserting some data. An example (adjustments needed to match your app name) below. You can either generate an empty migration (recommended) or append [RunCommand](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython)  into an existing migration.

To generate a new empty migration run [makemigrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations)

```
$ manage.py makemigrations your_app_name --empty
```

then edit the migration and add `RunPython` there (see linked docs above).

```
from django.db import migrations

def insert_blogpost(apps, schema_editor):
    BlogPost = apps.get_model('your_app_name', 'BlogPost')
    post = BlogPost(title="hello", body="post content")
    post.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('your_app_name', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(insert_blogpost),
    ]
```

Comment: Will it add multiple instances to `model` ? If yes then how will i add multiple instances at same time ?

Comment: The same way as you would do it in a normal code - you will create multiple instances one after another.